# select option which were just appended with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, append, html-select

Based on an AJAX query I appended some options to a list.

```
for(var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
    var data = options[i];
    var option = $('<option id="mySelectElementOption_' + data['id'] + '" value="' + data['value'] + '">' + data['value'] + '</option>');
    $('#mySelectElement').append(option);
}
```

Now when the user interacts on the page i want to select on of the just appended options and i tried the following (both possibilities don't work for me):

```
$('#mySelectElementOption_' + id).attr('selected', 'selected');
```

and

```
var option = document.getElementById('mySelectElementOption_' + id);
option.selected = true;
```

So I'm stuck, because I don't know how to select my option. Do you have any idea(s) how I can solve this?
Thanks!

**P.S.: When I try second possibility in Google Chrome it works perfectly.**

Greetings, Joseph

Comment: Try `$('#mySelectElement').val($('#mySelectElementOption_' + id).val());`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var opts = {

success: function(data)
         {
             //do everything here first before appending it,
             //including adding event bindings
         }

}

$.ajax(opts)
```

Comment: well the thing is that the user has to trigger the event first, so that the option gets selected afterwards.

Comment: you can add the binding there and even the function to execute on click, and THEN append it.

Comment: i mean if the AJAX query succeeds then options are appended to the list.

in other words the AJAX query requests the options for mySelectElement and appends them. then the user can trigger an event, e.g. select from another list an id and that id corresponds to one of the options i have just appended to mySelectElement.

Comment: okay i think i got what you meant! when the user selects the id from **another** list this triggers the query again, but this time i pass over the id which should be selected on success, while the options are beeing appended! :) thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 0):

Use `prop` instead of `attr`:

```
$('#mySelectElementOption_' + id).prop('selected', true);
```

or

```
$('#mySelect').val($('#mySelectElementOption_' + id).val());
```

http://jsfiddle.net/uG88d/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <select id="mySelectElement">
    <option id="oldoption" >Old option</option>
  </select>
</body>
</html>
```

JS:

```
//demo data
options = [{id:0, value:"aaa"},{id:1, value:"bbb"},{id:2, value:"ccc"}];

    for(var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
        var data = options[i];
        var option = $('<option id="mySelectElementOption_' + data['id'] + '" class="interactable" value="' + data['value'] + '">' + data['value'] + '</option>');
        $('#mySelectElement').append(option);
    }
//This is what you need:
        $("#mySelectElement :not([class])").attr("disabled","disabled");
```

Explanation:
`$("#mySelectElement :not([class=interactable])")` - This tells jquery to find any option element in the #mySelectElement that does not have the 'interactable' class.
Then it disables it: `.attr("disabled","disabled");`

Try it out:
[jsBin](http://jsbin.com/avumoj/2/)

**Edit:**

```
$("#mySelectElement .interactable:first").prop('selected', true);
```

[Try it out](http://jsbin.com/avumoj/4/)

Comment: ah okay this "does" something. but i don't need to disable my options, those should then be used later. i rather need to select something like a default value.

**EDIT:** and btw. all old options are removed completely, only new options are appended.